# Project Euler 5. How can I add elements to an ArrayList from other ArrayLists for which has the highest occuring number of primes

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Five {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        SupportLibrary sL = new SupportLibrary();

        for ( int i = 1; i <= 20; i ++ ){

            list = sL.primeFactorList(i);
            for ( int x = 0; x < list.size(); x ++ ){
                System.out.print( list.get(x) );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code and here's my output

```
2
3
22
5
23
7
222
33
25
11
223
13
27
35
2222
17
233
19
225
```

I'm trying to add only the 2222 33  5 7 11 13 17 19 to list1 so that I can multiply them to get the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20. Any ideas how?

Comment: How do you know that 2222 33 5 7 11 13 17 19 are the numbers needed to get your answer?

Comment: Because the number that I'm trying to get to, should incorporate all the prime numbers from 1-20 and 2 is a subset of 2222( 16's prime factorization ). Basically the number that is divisible by all 1-20 should contain those prime numbers. It's a math rule.

Comment: How can you can efficiently store 2222 33 5 7 11 13 17 19 in another ArrayList though?

Comment: Ah, I was confused because you had a typo. You mean to say 3, not 33.

Answer (score 1):

For what you described in your comments, you can do this:

```
if(list.get(x) == 2222 || list.get(x) <= 20){
   list1.add(x)
}
```

However, it seems like you already know the answer, and you're trying to fit your program to it. The point of Project Euler is that your program should derive the answer for you. Ideally, your program would be able to find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers of any range.

Try and think about *how* you know that 2222 is a factor. What made you choose that number specifically, and not any of the other numbers that have a prime factorization with numbers from 1 to 20?